# ReactJS Different Classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Iam new to ReactJS and I am working on a filterable gallery but now Iam looking at an example of thinking in ReactJS and I saw that they are building different classes for each component. I didn't do that but now Iam trying to do this, First my code looked like this: `

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { text:'', array: this.props.array};
  },
  handleChange(event) {
    var array = this.filterList(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ text: event.target.value, array: array });

    return this.state.text;
  },
  render() {     
      var arrayComponents = this.state.array.map(function(photo) {
         return <li className="photo photo-name">{photo.name} <img className="photo" src={photo.link}/></li>;
      });

    return <div>
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
      <p>{this.state.text}</p>
      <input type="text"  onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <ul>
        {arrayComponents}
      </ul>
    </div>;
  },
  filterList (filterText) {
    var updatedList = this.props.array, 
        filterTextLength = filterText.length;

    return updatedList.filter(function(item){
        var splitName = item.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, filterTextLength);
        var lowerCaseFilterText = filterText.toLowerCase();
        return splitName === lowerCaseFilterText;
    });
  }
});
```

Now I want to create an other Class of ImageList which has to include the `var arrayComponents` but if i do this:

```
var ImageList = React.createClass({
  render() {     
      var arrayComponents = this.props.array.map(function(photo) {
         return <li className="photo photo-name">{photo.name} <img className="photo" src={photo.link}/></li>;
      });
    <ul>
      {arrayComponents}
    </ul>
  }
})
```

and than in the render function add `<ImageList array={array}/>` instead of `<ul>{arrayComponent}</ul>` it throws me the error that `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` How do I pass the state of array into that ImageList class.

Here is a codepen: [LINK](http://codepen.io/smgjrein/pen/wzyKbg?editors=0010)

Comment: That `<ul>` is outside of the return... Also, just pass the `array` as a prop when using the component: `<ImageList array={array_here} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the following changes in your code: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/zKRAGZ

1) Pass the state of array into that `ImageList` class

```
<ImageList array={this.state.array} />
```

2) Add a `return` statement in the `render` method of `ImageList`

```
// Add return
    return (
      <ul>
        {arrayComponents}
      </ul>
    );
```

3) Add `key` attribute to the `li` tag when using map method:

```
      var arrayComponents = this.props.array.map(function(photo, index) {
// -------------------------------
// Add index to the li tag
// ----------------vvvvvvvvvvv
        return <li key={index} className="photo photo-name">{photo.name} <img className="photo" src={photo.link}/></li>;
      });
```

React Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the current state of the array.  So your component declaration should look like this:

```
<ImageList array={this.state.array}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I glance three problems here.
First,

```
var ImageList = React.createClass({
  render() {     
      var arrayComponents = this.props.array.map(function(photo) {
         return <li className="photo photo-name">{photo.name} <img className="photo" src={photo.link}/></li>;
      });
    <ul>
      {arrayComponents}
    </ul>
  }
})
```

you should say:

```
return (<ul>
      {arrayComponents}
    </ul>)
```

Second, when you use dynamically generated codes, you should add a `key` prop to it:

```
 var arrayComponents = this.props.array.map(function(photo) {
         return <li key={SOME_KEY} className="photo photo-name">{photo.name} <img className="photo" src={photo.link}/></li>;
      });
```

Third, in your codepen when you say :

```
<ImageList array={array}/>
```

you are referencing the global variable `array` (you declare it on the top of your code), do you mean:

```
<ImageList array={this.state.array}/>
```